# IIS Web Service Error Occurred - Might be CORS related

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am running into a strange issue with What I believe to be IIS related. I have developed an ASP.NET Web API running on DOTNET4.6. This API receives a json payload in its body when it is called from a different system. It then takes that information and calls the GitHub API at api.github.com with a personal access token in order to create a repository for me.

The outline above might be irrelevant to the situation but here is the problem:

**Problem**

When running in debug mode, this API works as expected. I can do postman POST request and all operations are completed as expected and I can see my new repo on GitHub.

When publishing the service and moving it to one of our IIS servers. Thing start to get messy and annoying. Doing a POST request results in a json response {"message":"An error has occurred"}. I know for a fact that this happens before my code is even reached and these are not one of my error handling messages. The response is a 500 Internal Server Error.

**What I have tried**

I tried investigating the source of the issue bu running the request in different ways. IIS logs give me nothing.

I ran the following request in the Chrome Developer console:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var raw = JSON.stringify({"timestamp":1589452400243,"webhookEvent":"item_created"});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://myiisserver/Integration/api/GitRepoSetu?clientid=aclientid&clientsecret=aclientsecret", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

unfortunately, this yields the same result and there is no useful information whatsoever. only a 500 internal server an a message stating "An error has occurred"

can anybody point me in the right direction as to where I can look to find an indication of what is actually going on? Previously, I had CORS policy issues and attempted to resolve them by installing the CORS NuGet package and configuring it on my Controller. The cors error were only thrown in the chrome dev console and never in postman. I am at my witts end trying to figure this out.

Comment: Use FRT to track down the actual error https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis, and use CORS module for relevant settings, https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module

Comment: Http 500 error typically indicates that the server is not running properly. For example, Asp.net runtime is not installed on the server,
I doubt there is something wrong with Asp.net WebAPI running state. Please check certain windows feature support, such as Asp.Net extension. Have you tried to create a PostMan Get request to the WebAPI? or, directly access it from the browser.

Comment: @AbrahamQian, A get request works perfectly to the same controller and returns the default controller value of Value1 and Value2. Even the home controller serves the default home page.

Comment: Asp.Net WebAPI have enabled the Help page by default, please try to access the Help controller for learning more about how to call the methods.
http://localhost:50866/Help

https://i.stack.imgur.com/th9EO.png
Besides, CORS issues only occurred on the frontend invocation (Javascript invocation) since JS has the Same-origin policy.